Ошибка при билде webpack
Есть такой проект на ts + webpack
./ts-project - корневая директория
./ts-project/src - директория с кодом
./ts-project/dist - директория куда компилится тс

В src лежит webpack.config.js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.ts',
  mode: 'development',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
};

В корне лежат package.json
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-loader": "^9.5.1",
    "typescript": "^5.6.3",
    "webpack": "^5.95.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^5.1.0"
  },
  "name": "ts-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}

И tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "strict": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "lib": [
            "es6",
            "dom"
        ],
        "rootDir": "src",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "outDir": "dist"
    }
}

При команде npm run build выдает следующую ошибку

Can't resolve './src' in 'C:\Users\dhelfy\Documents\ts-project'
resolve './src' in 'C:\Users\dhelfy\Documents\ts-project'   using
description file: C:\Users\dhelfy\Documents\ts-project\package.json
(relative path: .)

Не пойму в чем проблема? Перегуглил кучу похожих ситуаций, но ничего не помогает, выручайте
